# How to disable forcing "Project needs to be converted to androidx.* dependencies " when creating new module in Android Studio?

Tags: android, module

Currently; I have a Android Studio project with multiple modules. When I want to add new module via wizard in New File > New module, An red error message is shown in bottom of window:

```
Project needs to be converted to androidx.* dependencies
```

[image]

But I don't want refactoring my codes from support library to jetpack (androidX). How can I disable this change force?

Comment: AFAIK there is no other way but to migrate your project to androidX libraries.

Comment: As of November 2nd, 2020 - All apps are required to migrate to AndroidX to use most major libraries. This includes all Jetpack libraries, Google Play services, Firebase, Butterknife, Databinding Mockito, and SQL Delight among many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution:

1. In gradle.properties disable these options:

```
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
```

2. In sdk-manager, uninstall android Q platform tools

Comment: I also had some straggling androidx dependencies in my build.gradle that I'd forgotten about that I had to remove. I didn't have to uninstall any platform tools though.

Comment: The second step can not be ignored in my case. When I just do the first step the problem is still exist ,but after all this two steps the problem has gone.Thank you for your answer @ofskyMohsen