# Android Studio - create new module for Wear OS, how to ignore "Project needs to be converted to androidx.* dependencies"?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I have an existing Android Studio project which is imported from Unity3d, and I want to add a new module for Wear OS. However, I can't create the module because it says "Project needs to be converted to androidx.* dependencies". How can I ignore this warning and not convert the project to androidx?

I saw this post [How to disable forcing "Project needs to be converted to androidx.* dependencies " when creating new module in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467281/how-to-disable-forcing-project-needs-to-be-converted-to-androidx-dependencies) but the solution didn't work for me. Thanks in advance!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhmiT.png)

Comment: Any specific reason you don't want to convert to androidx? Since 2019, all new Jetpack libraries are released under AndroidX and (as I understand) migration is required to use them. Your link is from 2019, which I think late 2020 that solution no longer works as migration is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. I converted to androidx and added "android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true" in gradle.properties, then I can add a new module.